# I'm trying to creat an array where I'm getting information from a json file. but the result is coming in one line

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I expect to get the user and password one by one from the JSON file, but instead, the output is coming in one line.

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents("URL");
$details = json_decode($json);
foreach($details->{'user'} as $output) {
    $username = $output->{'username'};
    $password = $output->{'password'};
    $LOGIN_INFORMATION = array(
        "$username" => "$password",
        'admin' => 'admin'
    );
}
```

I don't know how to formol my question in an easy way.
when a user is writing their username and password it doesn't log in because of all users is in one line.

[image]

Comment: Why do you write `$details->{'user'}` instead of `$details->user`?

Comment: You're overwriting the `$LOGIN_INFORMATION` variable each time through the loop. At the end it will just be the information from the last user in the JSON. If `$LOGIN_INFORMATION` is supposed to be an array, assign to `$LOGIN_INFORMATION[]` to push onto the array.

Comment: @Barmar Then what should I do to fix it?

Comment: See the last sentence of my previous comment. This is basic PHP syntax, not worth a full answer.

Comment: I'm not that good at this could you please recode and send it to me as a comment please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to push the data onto the array, not replace the variable each time through the loop. You do this by putting `[]` after the variable name in the assignment.

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents("URL");
$details = json_decode($json);
$LOGIN_INFORMATION = [];
foreach($details->user as $output) {
    $username = $output->username;
    $password = $output->password;
    $LOGIN_INFORMATION[] = array(
        "$username" => $password,
        'admin' => 'admin'
    );
}
var_dump($LOGIN_INFORMATION);
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/EOBdgk)

Comment: I just added a link to an online demo that shows that it works.

Comment: it should look more like this to work in my case
array(2) { ["dog"]=> string(3) "red" ["admin"]=> string(5) "admin" }

Comment: That's what I have, an array of arrays like that. The only exception is the first one, which is just `array("admin" => "admin")`. This is because the username is `admin`, and you can't have duplicate keys.

Comment: What do you mean by "get the user and password one by one". Do you want to check the username and password that the user has entered? Then you should compare them inside the loop.

Comment: Please take a look [Demo](https://ideone.com/EOBdgk#comments)

Comment: I don't understand. If you're looping over all the users, you need an array of results, not just one of them. Why are you only returning `dog`?

Comment: If you only want the last one in the array, there's no need for a loop.

Comment: Please check my comment on that demo link you send it to me, there i'm showing how it works on my page

Comment: I still don't understand. Where are all the other users in your desired result? The extra `{}` around my result is because it's a 2-dimensional array, with an element for every user.

Comment: You keep posting the same desired result over and over, but you've never explained where that result is supposed to come from in the loop. Why aren't `john` and `cat` in the desired result?

Comment: Here is the whole code. Can you please look at it? [New demo](https://ideone.com/k8iJIJ)

Comment: Are you trying to search the array for a specific username, and check if the password is correct?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry for I can't explain it in a good way.
Trying to make one PHP login page and use JSON to bring users and passwords to log in.

Comment: Just use an `if` statement in the loop, to test if the username matches the input. This is really simple.

Comment: Why aren't you using a database to hold the account information?

Comment: I'm using google script to have it all in my google sheets and that's safe I guess.

Comment: Did you check the code I published and taste it?

Comment: No, it was too long and I didn't feel like trying to figure out what it's doing. If you can't explain clearly what you're trying to do, I'm not going to spend any more time on this.

Comment: The code is a single PHP login page script, where I can manually add users and passwords on the same page. what I wanted is to bring users and passwords from a JSON file which will be easier for users to fill out from somewhere else. You did answer from the start the way I should make to create an array but that's not working. it takes probably a minute for you to fix it. To be honest with you I'm not that good at PHP